# Trying to get xauth to work with Ruby and the Readability API

Tags: ruby, oauth, readability, xauth

I'd like to use the Readability API through the [Readit gem](https://github.com/29decibel/readit); however, I've been having some trouble trying to get an access token through XAuth. Here's the code that I have:

```
require 'highline/import'
require 'yaml'
require 'oauth'
require 'readit'

config = YAML.load_file("config/readability.yaml")
uname = ask ("Username: ") 
passwd = ask ("Password: ") {|q| q.echo = false}

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(config["-consumer_key"], config["-consumer_secret"], :site => "https://www.readability.com/api/rest/v1/oauth/access_token/")
access_token = consumer.get_access_token(nil, {}, {:x_auth_mode => 'client_auth', :x_auth_username => uname, :x_auth_password => passwd})
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the following:

```
/Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/oauth-0.4.5/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:219:in `token_request': 404 NOT FOUND (OAuth::Unauthorized)
from /Users/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/oauth-0.4.5/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:109:in `get_access_token'
from instab.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Behrang, have you been able to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You should write as follows:

```
consumer = ::OAuth::Consumer.new(Readit::Config.consumer_key,Readit::Config.consumer_secret,:site=>"https://www.readability.com/", :access_token_path => "/api/rest/v1/oauth/access_token/")
```

Comment: check the readability access_token request path, it was different to the default.